# Repeat relative positions in the node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I made a figure below using a tikz figure. In node (3) and (4) I use equal relative commands. It works!

I would like to switch to a better option for multiple repetitions (4 times for example) relative commands. I need distances to be relative in my complex problem so "node distance = 4cm" does not help.

In node (5) I have a sucess change `below of = 1, right of = 1` for `below right = of 1` (with library `positioning` and optional parameter `on grid`)

```
\documentclass[border = 2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,rectangle},on grid]
\draw[help lines] (-1,1) grid (3,-5);
\begin{scope}%[node distance= 1cm and 1cm]
 \node (1) at (0,0) {1}; 
 \node [below of = 1] (2) {2};
 \node [below of = 1, below of = 1,below of = 1,below of = 1] (3) {3};
 \node [right of = 1, right of = 1] (4) {4};
%\node [below of = 1, right of = 1] (5) {5};
 \node [below right = of 1] (5) {5};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You're not actually using the `positioning` library here, but deprecated old syntax. `positioning` has `<position>=of <othernode>`, you're using `<position> of=<othernode>`.

Comment: Multiple `below=of` doesn't do anything special, the last one will overwrite the previous ones. Are you after e.g. `below = 4cm of 1` for the `3` node?

Comment: Yes!! I use `positioning` only in new node (5). In the rest nodes not influence in my problem.

Comment: I need for alternative for don't usign absolut distances! I need change de `node distance` in future.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question a bit. I don't quite understand what you mean by changing `node distance` in the future, but you could perhaps add `\newcommand\nd{1}`, use `node distance=\nd cm and \nd cm`, and e.g. `4*\nd cm of 1`. That way you can specify the distance in multiples of the `node distance`. Does that sound promising?

Comment: Yes! Seems interesting! I can not do it now, but I'll try!

Comment: Why don't you just use a matrix, assuming you want them on a grid?

Comment: It would be very difficult to move the points in my real problem. This was just a minimal example showing the problem. In the my "big figure" the node (1) is positioned in another point. In my case with relative position it is easier to modify parts of figure without having to redefine all the positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick example, don't have time for more right now.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border = 2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={draw,rectangle},
  on grid
]
\newcommand\nd{1}
\draw[help lines] (-1,1) grid (3,-3);
\begin{scope}[node distance=\nd cm and \nd cm]
 \node (1) at (0,0) {1}; 
 \node [below = of 1] (2) {2};
 \node [below = 4*\nd cm of 1] (3) {3};
 \node [right = 2*\nd of 1] (4) {4};
 \node [below right = of 1] (5) {5};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```